# many "two dots" (parent directory) in path

Tags: c++, gcc

By dumping the options of **gcc** using `gcc -Q -v any_C_file.c`
I found, among others, this option

```
#include <...> search starts here:
/internaltools/opt/gcc-4.3.2p/bin/../lib/gcc/../../include
```

Is there reason why the system administrator has used so many "parent directory" in the path which is simply `/internaltools/opt/gcc-4.3.2p/include`?

Comment: Probably because they were specified as relative paths.

Comment: This is not uncommon when the source code is organized into nested directories in a hierarchy. The include directory may be a subdirectory of the root, and code directories will reach it by going up several levels.

Comment: @Barmar but how to explain this complex `go up one directory(../) then go down two directory(/lib/gcc/) then again go up two directories(../../) then go down again one direcotory(include)`?

Comment: Because compiling something in one directory needed to run a makefile in a the directory `../lib/gcc`, so that got prepended. Then that makefile used `../../include`.